# MySQL Trigger to update a table based on changes on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I've been working for this seemingly simple task for hours with no luck.

I have a database, **test**, which contains two tables: **room** and **reservation**.

In table **room** there is a column named *reserved_status* with possible values of 0 and 1. *room_id* is its primary key.

In table **reservation**, there is the *room_id* column, which refers to the room_id from table **room**

Basically, I want to create a trigger, that updates *reserved_status* to 1, whenever there is a change in table **reservation**(Like insert, update or delete).

The following query is actually accepted in phpMyAdmin:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER reserved_status_insert AFTER
INSERT ON
 reservation FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE
 room
SET
 room_reserved = 1
WHERE
 room_id = NEW.reservation.room_id ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I try to do a insert operation, it gives me this error:

```
Unknown column 'NEW.reservation.room_id' in 'where clause'
```

I hope someone can provide me a suitable solution, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `NEW.reservation.room_id` use `NEW.room_id`, since `NEW` already refers to the new row in the `reservation` table.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it... Honestly mad that I didn't see that syntax through, such a simple mistake.